# How to populate select controls in a loop, by class name, with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to populate a collection of select elements, using jQuery, via class selector, in a loop.

For a reason unknown to me, I am unable to use the following:

```
$('.mySelectClass option:last').before(html);
```

I would like to use something like the following:

```
$.each($('.mySelectClass'), function (idx, ctrl) {
   $(this).select('option:last').before(html);
});
```

My question is, how do I use this syntax to insert the option in this way?  I haven't been able to find an example anywhere that combines the use of $(this) with 'option:last' in this way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe your starting html and your expected ending html?

Comment: Could be that you want `$(".mySelectClass").find('option:last-child').before(html);` - `:last-child` will select all the `:last` from *all* the `select`s, so no need for a loop.  Will also work in a loop if you have some other actions to perform.  Ideally need that before/after HTML to provide a complete/valid solution

Comment: Yes, this is EXACTLY what I wanted, thank you very much!  I had tried the same thing, but with "select" instead of "find".  I appreciate the help!